# code fail at grailsApplication.config.grails.binRange. any one can solve this?

Tags: grails, grails-3.3.x

We are upgrading grails 2.4.4 to 3.6.6, but the code failed at grailsApplication.config.grails.binRange. Any idea why I am not able to access grails from config. anyone can solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default configuration file for Grails 3 applications is `grails-app/conf/application.yml`. In this file, **YAML** syntax is supported.

The **GrailsApplication** interface defines the `getConfig` method which returns a Config object. In the Spring application context is a bean named `grailsApplication` which is an instance of a class which implements the `GrailsApplication` interface. Retrieving the config object from this bean is one way to gain access to config values.

For Example:
**grails-app/conf/application.yml**

```
max:
    line:
        numbers: 42
```

OR

```
max.line.numbers: 42
```

**grails-app/init/BootStrap.groovy**

```
import grails.core.GrailsApplication

class YourController{

    GrailsApplication grailsApplication

        // retrieve the max.line.numbers config value
        def maxLineNumbers =  grailsApplication.config.getProperty('max.line.numbers')

}
```

Reference [this](http://grailsblog.objectcomputing.com/posts/2016/08/31/retrieving-config-values.html) and [this](https://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/conf.html)

Hope this will helps you

Comment: Thank you so much Rahul, this is very useful for me.

Comment: Hi Rahul, thanks for this answer as it was also useful to me. Do you know if the configs defined in the application.yml file is accessible directly from a gsp template by doing something like ${grailsApplication.config.max.line.numbers} ? or do I have to add the bean to the respective controller in order to make it available? Thank you :)

Comment: @ZvKa In gsp you can access using this `${grailsApplication.config.get('max.line.numbers')}`

Comment: Thanks Rahul! one last question although it's a bit unrelated but since you sound like you're a Grails expert....I'm trying to use the Assets plugin to package a javascript library, particularly the ArcGIS JS API but I have not been successful and I think that's because the library uses AMD loading. Do you know if this is a true statement? Thanks again.